# Lotusscript JSON Navigator strange type being returned for string when using preferUTF8

Tags: json, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Doing something fairly simple with the JSON Parser within Lotusscript.  Call a Domino Web Agent with a GET, and passing as the body:

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
```

The Strange thing is, if I used preferUTF8 parameter the string is coming across with a type of 6, which is not documented.  If I don't use preferUTF8 then the string comes across with a type of 3.

Does anyone know why the difference?

Here is a snippet of the Lotusscript Code

```
Dim incomingJSONNav As NotesJSONNavigator
Dim incomingJSONElement As NotesJSONElement

Set incomingJSONNav = Session.CreateJSONNavigator(session.DocumentContext.Request_Content(0))
incomingJSONNav.Preferutf8 = True
Print IncomingJSONNav.Getelementbyname("name").type
Print IncomingJSONNav.Getelementbyname("age").type
Print IncomingJSONNav.Getelementbyname("car").type
```

If you use PreferUTF8= true this returns 6, 4, 64

if you used PreferUTF=false this returns 3, 4, 64

The documentation is pretty poor for the JSON classes, and it shows the return types as:

```
Jsonelem_type_array
Jsonelem_type_boolean
Jsonelem_type_empty
Jsonelem_type_number
Jsonelem_type_object
Jsonelem_type_string
```

but doesn't actually say what integer each is, so if anyone else ever needs this they are:

```
Jsonelem_type_object     1
Jsonelem_type_array      2
Jsonelem_type_string     3
Jsonelem_type_number     4
Jsonelem_type_boolean    5
Jsonelem_type_empty     64
```

Comment: So the answer is that the unknown type is a byte array.  Nothing I could find mentions this.